# регулярное выражения php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. хочу получит счет:

```
echo(preg_replace("/[^\d.]/", '', '182.20 Старая цена.'));
```

получаю:

```
182.20.
```

как мне получит только: **182.20**

Comment: Если после счета всегда пробел, то можо без регулярки `strstr('182.20 Старая цена.', ' ', true);`. В теории даже должно работать быстрее.

Comment: ну на всякий запасной хорошо бы только счет получит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цену можно извлечь, например, так:

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/
```

а с помощью `preg_replace` заменить следующим образом:

```
$value = preg_replace("/.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*/", "$1", $str);
```

Но, возможно,  для ваших целей будет достаточно следующего?

```
 $str = '182.20 Старая цена.';
 $value = trim(stri_replace("старая цена.", "", $str));
```

---

**Что происходит здесь, и почему не работает ваше выражение.**

- В своем выражении вы удаляете (заменяете на пустоту) все символы
  отличные от точки `\.` и цифр `\d`. Поэтому последняя точка также
  остается на месте. Если ваша входная строка будет иметь вид `123.345.456.890` то вся эта конструкция подойдет под это выражение результат.
- В приведенном в начале ответа выражении из строки извлекается число, с возможно дробной частью.
  Первая часть `\d+` соответствуюет целой части.
  Длаее идет группа для дробной части `(?:\.\d+)?`. Здесь во-первых, конечный знак `?` говорит о том, что этой группы может и не быть. Начальная конструкция `?:` в скобках говорит, что ее не надо захватывать (non-capturing group). Внутри же группы должна находится точка `.\`и 1 или более цифр `\d+`.

Таким образом, приведенное выражение просто соответствуюет любому целому или дробному числу с разделителем точкой.

Comment: Извините вырезать т,е получит только `182.20`

Comment: @newProgrammer дописал про `preg_replaceё`

Comment: Спасибо работает, а вы специально взяли такое сложное выражения? например вот так `[^\d.]` я получал то что хотел, только в точке ошибся.

Comment: @newProgrammer расписал подробней, что тут и как. Выражение на самом деле не сложное :)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/', '182.20 Старая цена.', $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
else {
    // Неправильная цена
}
```

Comment: Ввел изменения в тему =) сори

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно более короткий способ использовать для этого просто привести к float строку

```
<?php

$string = '182.20 Старая stauagvu a цена.';
echo (float)$string;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/214972ada960fe609965f9e1d66b46772d21c81a

Comment: а да так тоже хорошо, но надо и копейки учесть.

Comment: @newProgrammer в математике нет числа `182.20` есть `182.2` вы можете использовать `sprintf` с ключом `%f` для форматирвоания ввывода до копеек или же `number_format`

Comment: Да нет, но в маем случае result будет хранится в базе что бы потом выводит. все же спасибо за вариант

Comment: @newProgrammer если в mysql поле типа флоат то там по умолчанию до 100 т.е. 00 после запятой будет сотых.